# Why is Hinduism male centric in terms of marriage and family?

Tags: scripture, vedas, vishnu, lakshmi

If a child inherently has genes of both mother and father then why is the Gotra decided on patrilineal basis and not from mothers lineage? Is female body so exception to humanity?

Why in Hindu scriptures do couples yearn for the birth of a male child so much? Does a female child have lesser potential? Hindu scriptures at times have shown fighter/warrior queens/princesses, even then why do parent Kings and queens perform specific yajnas to beget male child? Some say that a daughter can't perform shraddh/tarpan. Can someone tell any reason why can't she? Does she lack something that son or a male body has?

Why are daughters given as donation/daan to grooms? Is such a donation of a human, just because she has a female body, dharmic? Why does physicality matter so much in marriage and family?
Just because of having a female body, a natural occurrence, a human is not getting the basic rights that would’ve gotten if they had a male body!

There have been always heavy traditions for females than males, from sindur to sati or tonsuring of head and wearing of white clothes after husbands death. I know that ancient women willingly wore sindur etc but why? My question is who created this tradition and why only for women? My question basically is that why are all these traditions related to marriage linked with women only? Is marriage a women's whole life or just a  part of her life?

Can anyone explain that why these marriage rituals and traditions are linked to women only and not ever to men? Is there any proper, real and satisfactory justification for this? Tonsuring women's head and making her look unattractive to men doesn't really solve the problem of rapes. This is basically a torture to women rather than punishing the real issue of lusty rapists. This leaves less difference in burkha and white clothes. Hiding and avoiding women's beauty would pressurize men with more lust even.

Is this gender bias really in accordance with dharma? I don't even care about people! I just want to know why goddesses too followed patriarchal practices like kanyadan, leaving home after marriage, etc? Why did they support these biases?

Comment: Hello Curious Questioner. I think your question might be a little too broad. Can you maybe narrow it down to one, or perhaps break your questions down into multiple questions and ask all of them separately?

Comment: I would consume pretty much time which I am running out of right now that's why I asked it all in single one question and after all the topic is same, "Patriarchy".

Comment: The concept of equality of sexes is hardly a century old while Hinduism is around 30 centuries old. And you are expecting that such a grand old religion must mould itself to fit the expectations of such a recent ideology (that too formulated by foreigners).

Comment: Regarding kanyadana, there is much misinformation circulating in the Internet these days. Adoption was also a religious rite complete with fire-rituals similar to marriage, in which the biological father did 'donate' his son to the adoptive father, similar to performing kanyadana. However after Ambedkar passed the Hindu code bills in the 1960s, adoption ceased to be a Hindu religious rite. Why selective outrage over kanyadana in marriage but silence over putradana in adoption ?

Comment: You said your question pretty much is "patriarchy". That belongs on a stack exchange related to human development accross religious lines, and not in Hinduism Stack Exchange forum. All religions are male centric, with Islam and Christianity being the most outspoken ones. At least Hindusim allows us to worship God in feminine forms, which is a sacrliege in Islam and Christianity & Judaism.

Comment: By the same incorrect logic of gender equality, men can also question why this religion doesn't give them privilege to be a house-husband and attain heaven merely by serving family. Manu says men(father,husband,son) have to protect women but no such burden is placed on women to protect men. Men have to stake life in battle etc. If there are 10 rules for women there are 1000 rules for men. This religion works on horse for courses approach. Other religions have much less rules for men but that's their problem not ours. We don't have to blame ours for gender disparity in other religion.

Comment: Ambedkar or any other politician are no authority on religion. Democracy works on votes; women , shudras are high in numbers and hence by cherry picking verses pertaining to only women, it is easy to get votes from larger sections of society and win elections